# Pyside WebView example showing blank screen

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I'm starting to play with QWebView in PySide.

I can load HTML into the web view and view it, however I can't seem to load online pages or set urls. Here is the example I've got:

```
import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtWebKit import *
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
web = QWebView()
web.setUrl(QUrl("https://www.google.com"))
web.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

All I get from this is a nice blank white window. Anyone know what's missing?

Comment: Could you clarify the Python, PySide and Qt version? Can't reproduce with Python 3.4, PyQt4 and Qt 4.8. Neither with Python 3.4, PyQt5 and Qt 5.3. Code looks fine.

Comment: I reckon it might be my work network or perhaps my PySide install. I'm using Python 3.4, PySide 1.2.2 and Qt 4.8

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are behind a proxy.
I've experienced the same behavior and setting a Proxy for the Application helped.

```
from PySide.QtNetwork import QNetworkProxy

proxy = QNetworkProxy()
proxy.setType(QNetworkProxy.Socks5Proxy);
proxy.setType(QNetworkProxy.HttpProxy);
proxy.setHostName("*********");
proxy.setPort(****);
QNetworkProxy.setApplicationProxy(proxy);
```